# Guardar valor de EditText con SharedPreferences y sin necesidad de utilizar un botón (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Quisiera saber si es posible almacenar la información de un `EditText` sin necesidad de cliquear en ningún tipo de botón, es decir, que al mismo tiempo en el que el usuario escribe se pueda guardar, y estar accesible cuando la aplicación vuelva a arrancar. La idea sería que la primera vez que el usuario inicie la aplicación, pudiera ingresar sus datos manualmente, y en ese instante se guardarán, para que al volver a recargar la aplicación estuviesen disponibles y visibles para el usuario.

Mi aplicación se inicia con esta vista, y lo que quiero hacer es guardar los datos al mismo tiempo que se escriben.

[image: Pregunta concreta]

La cosa está en que si tuviese un botón sería bastante fácil guardarlo, pero quisiera hacerlo sin botón. Mi idea es guardarlo con `sharedPreferences`, aunque el `DNI` también lo guardaré con `SQLite`. Sé que `EditText` tiene estos eventos:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // Fires right as the text is being changed (even supplies the range of text)
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // Fires right before text is changing
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // Fires right after the text has changed
    }
});
```

Pero, ¿cómo hago para que una vez escriba el valor pueda guardarlo? Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia, quieres que use configuraciones, archivos, base de datos? Mira el articulo [Opciones de almacenamiento](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html?hl=es-419) para los detalles. Tienes código de muestra? Luego que aclares esto edita la pregunta :P

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html además de opciones de almacenamiento https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html?hl=es-419  y realizar tu pregunta especifica, agregando lo que hayas tratado.

Comment: simplemente consigues el contenido del EditText completo en `afterTextChanged` y luego lo guardas en `SharedPreferencespref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);` te da las preferencias, luego lo guardas con `prefs.edit().putString(key,value).commit()`. Como el tema esta demasiado amplio, te tengo que dar la respuesta en un comentario, disculpa. ;)

Comment: Te recomiendo de evitar imágenes en preguntas, y usarlo solamente en casos que es necesario para demostrar algo.

Comment: Muchas gracias @StefanNolde me has aclarado la duda. Trataré de incorporar imágenes sólo cuando haya que demostrar algo, gracias por el consejo. ;)

Comment: @Mariano he editado la pregunta para que se vea más clara, y pueda ayudar a aquellos que se hayan planteado la misma pregunta que yo, pero no sé como reabrir el post ¿?

Comment: @Aico muchas gracias! Recién voté para reabrir. Es cuestión de esperar a otros revisores para que se reabra

Comment: @Aico ahora si parece una "pregunta" hehe, muchas gracias, ahora tendrás seguramente ayuda de las personas del sitio.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes conseguir el contenido del `EditText` completo en `afterTextChanged` y luego lo guardas como:

```
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        // te da las preferencias
        prefs.edit().putString("editText",s.toString()).commit(); // guardarlos
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Lo que quiero hacer es guardar los datos al mismo tiempo que se
> escriben.

Te comentaré que puedes ir guardando los datos al momento que vas escribiendo cada carácter como lo estas realizando, usando la clase [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html), sin embargo en el caso de una forma donde se guardan valores, no es una buena práctica, la razón es simplemente porque los datos al final se requieren completos, el nombre, el teléfono, etc. Lo mejor es tener una vista que realicé la acción de guardarlos al final del llenado de la forma.

---

Si deseas guardar el valor al momento de escribir cada carácter el método usado es `onTextChanged()`, puedes usar SharedPreferences, una base de datos o cualquier otro método de almacenamiento:

```
@Override    
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //valor a guardar.
        saveValue(getApplicationContext(), s.toString());
    }
```

Como ejemplo puede ser **[getSharedPreferences()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getSharedPreferences())** :

```
private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferencias";

public void saveValue(Context context, String text) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("valorEditText", text);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getValue(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);

    return  preferences.getString("valorEditText", "");
}
```

para que cargué el valor al iniciar simplemente carga el valor obtenido de las preferencias, por medio del método `getValue()` sugerido, esto podría ser dentro de `onCreate()` de tu `Activity`:

```
editText.setText(getValue(getApplicationContext()));
```